# Calculating a discount

Tags: java

I'm looking for a reason why this code will only use the 10% discount scenario listed below no matter what I input for the discountPercentage input message box. I need to make it so that the only percentages that will be calculated are 10%, 15%, or 25%. If a user enters anything else into the discountPercentage  input message box, the discount will default to 10% off price 1.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class  Assignment3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Calculate the discount price of an item

        // Convert price to display as decimal format
            DecimalFormat df = new
            DecimalFormat("#,###,##0.00");

        // Declare discountPercentage variable    


        // Display message boxes for price and percentage entries
        double price1 = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, " Enter item price (ex:2.35): "));
        double discountPercentage = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, " Enter discount percentage "));
        int dicountPercentage = 0;

        // Declare if else statements for output calculations
           if (discountPercentage > 25){

           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " The discounted price is: " + "$" + df.format(price1 - .10 * price1));

           }else if (dicountPercentage == 25){

           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " The discounted price is: " + "$" + df.format(price1 - .25 * price1));

           } else if (discountPercentage > 15){

           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " The discounted price is: " + "$" + df.format(price1 - .10 * price1));

           } else if (dicountPercentage == 15){

           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " The discounted price is: " + "$" + df.format(price1 - .15 * price1));

           } else if (discountPercentage >= 10){

           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " The discounted price is: " + "$" + df.format(price1 - .10 * price1));

                                            }
                                }
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you use multiple ifs if you could just calculate the ratio from the discount directly?

Comment: Well, have you stepped through the code in the debugger to see what path it is taking?

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm 100% new to Java programming. Just started this Java class a couple weeks ago. Learning as I go. The coding issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code will use the 10% scenario every time because in all the conditions on `discountPercentage`, you use the value `.10`, this exact same line every time:

> ```
>        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " The discounted price is: " + "$" + df.format(price1 - .10 * price1));
> ```

That is, in all these conditions you have that same line:

> ```
>        if (discountPercentage > 25){
>        } else if (discountPercentage > 15){
>        } else if (discountPercentage >= 10){
> ```

Also note that you have two variables in this code with almost the same name:

- `dicountPercentage`
- `discountPercentage`

And the first variable is set 0 and never changes,
so all the conditions using `dicountPercentage` are pointless.
And this kind of naming is very bad:
avoid using variables with very similar names.
(At first I didn't even notice there were two variables,
I thought both are one and the same...)

Comment: Thanks Janos. As you can tell, I'm a beginner, and this is my first Java course.I didn't even notice the variable naming difference. I removed the "dicountPercentage" as that one was incorrect. The coding issue has been fixed. Thanks for the fast response!

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class  Assignment3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Calculate the discount price of an item

        // Convert price to display as decimal format
        DecimalFormat df = new
        DecimalFormat("#,###,##0.00");

        // Declare discountPercentage variable    


        // Display message boxes for price and percentage entries
        double price1 = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, " Enter item price (ex:2.35): "));
        double discountPercentage = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, " Enter discount percentage "));
        //int dicountPercentage = 0;

        // Declare if else statements for output calculations
        switch(discountPercentage)
        {
        case 25:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " The discounted price is: " + "$" + df.format(price1 - .25 *price1));
            break;

        case 15:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " The discounted price is: " + "$" + df.format(price1 - .15 *price1));
            break;

        default:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " The discounted price is: " + "$" + df.format(price1 - .10 *price1));
            break;
        }
    }
```